# pandas.error.invalidindex error at a place where it doesn't make any sense

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, termux, termux-linux

I have been getting a weird error that I'm not able to explain with any online source. I've been working on a school project.I tried assigning some input values into a list. The list was going to be used to define a new row into the existing dataframe, during which I encountered the error:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["First_Name","Last_Name","Aadhar_No.","city","DOB","Age","DOA","DOR",'sentence_indays',"sentence_inyears","crime"])

if os.path.exists("Criminaldb.csv"):

    print("Welcome back!")

else:

    print("Kindly please restart the program after this process is completed.")

    with open("Criminaldb.csv",'w') as file:

        pass

    df.to_csv("Criminaldb.csv",mode='a')

    exit()

print('''Welcome to Criminal prison DB record app! 

What do you wish to do today?

1) Add new entry

2) Update previous record

3) Find and sort old records

4) Delete a record

5) Exit the program''')

choice = int(input())

if choice == 1:

    print("Please fill out the asked details in the suggested formats only.")

    total_entries = int(input("How many entries are to be done?(Numeric values only)"))

    for i in range(1,total_entries+1):

        print("Entry no. ",i )

        first_name=input("First name ")

        last_name=input("Last name ")

        Aadhar = input("Aadhar no. ")

        city = input("Enter the city name(First letter capital)")

        cmnl_ID = input("Crimimal ID assigned ")

        DOB = input("Date of Birth(YYYYMMDD format) ")

        year,month,day= DOB[:4],DOB[4:6],DOB[6:9]

        if month[0] == '0':

            month = month[1]

        if day[0]  == '0':

            day = day[1]

        else:

            pass

        ageindays = date(int(year),int(month),int(day))

        age = date.today() - ageindays

        age = int(age.days/365)

        DOA = input("Date of admission(Same format as before)")

        if DOA == '':

            DOA = date.today()

        else:

            yr_adm, mon_adm, day_adm = DOA[:4],DOA[4:6],DOA[6:9]

            if mon_adm[0] == '0':

                mon_adm = mon_adm[1]

            if yr_adm[0] == '0':

                yr_adm = yr_adm[1]

            else:

                pass

        DOA = date(int(yr_adm),int(mon_adm),int(day_adm))

        DOR = input("Date of Release(Same format as before,leave blank for life imprisonment) ")

        if DOR == '':

            DOR = 'N/A'

        else:

            yr_rel,mon_rel,day_rel = DOR[:4],DOR[4:6],DOR[6:9]

            if mon_rel[0] == '0':

                mon_rel = mon_rel[1]

            if day_rel[0] == '0':

                day_rel = day_rel[1]

        DOR = date(int(yr_rel),int(mon_rel),int(day_rel))

        total_sentence = DOR-DOA

        sentence_indays= total_sentence.days

        sentence_inyears= round(float(total_sentence.days)/365, 1)

        crime = input("Crime done by the criminal ")

        entrylist = {'First_Name':first_name,'Last_Name':last_name,'Aadhar_No':Aadhar,'city':city,'DOB':DOB,'Age':age,'DOA':DOA,'DOR':DOR,'sentence_indays':sentence_indays,'sentence_inyears':sentence_inyears,'crime':crime}

        df.at[str(cmnl_ID),:] = entrylist

         

if choice == '2':

    print("Please Remember to enter data in suggested formats only!")

    findCrim = input("Please give the Criminal ID of the criminal whose query you need to make changes to: ")

    with open('Criminaldb.csv','r') as finder:

        f2 = csv.reader(finder)

        for i in f2:

            if i[4] == findCrim:

                print("Entry found!")

                print('Current details:')

                for j in range(11):

                    print(fields[j],": ",i[j])

                print("Please proceed ")

            else:

                print("No entry with Criminal ID ",findCrim," found!")

                continue

if choice== '5':

    print("Exiting..")

    exit()
```

When using the "Add new entry" option of this code and providing it with the required inputs, it gives the following error:

[image]

Can anyone please help me out with this? Any relevant responses would be greatly appreciated.

Environment info:
Main env: Termux

Termux Variables:

```
TERMUX_APP_PACKAGE_MANAGER=apt

TERMUX_APP__AM_SOCKET_SERVER_ENABLED=true                                                                 TERMUX_APP__APK_PATH=/data/app/~~w5pcxTLDl6SFk1Zoh9vmlQ==/com.termux-3prOjAH5DyBS7ay61hWIkA==/base.apk

TERMUX_APP__APK_RELEASE=GITHUB

TERMUX_APP__FILES_DIR=/data/user/0/com.termux/files

TERMUX_APP__IS_DEBUGGABLE_BUILD=true                                                                      TERMUX_APP__IS_INSTALLED_ON_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=false

TERMUX_APP__PACKAGE_MANAGER=apt

TERMUX_APP__PACKAGE_NAME=com.termux                                                                       TERMUX_APP__PACKAGE_VARIANT=apt-android-5

TERMUX_APP__PID=15476

TERMUX_APP__SE_FILE_CONTEXT=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c87,c257,c512,c768

TERMUX_APP__SE_INFO=default:targetSdkVersion=28:complete

TERMUX_APP__SE_PROCESS_CONTEXT=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c87,c257,c512,c768

TERMUX_APP__TARGET_SDK=28

TERMUX_APP__UID=10343

TERMUX_APP__USER_ID=0                                                                                     TERMUX_APP__VERSION_CODE=118

TERMUX_APP__VERSION_NAME=0.118.0+a523911

TERMUX_MAIN_PACKAGE_FORMAT=debian                                                                         TERMUX_VERSION=0.118.0+a523911
```

Packages CPU architecture: aarch64

Subscribed repositories:

```
deb https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-main stable main

# sources.list.d/ivam3-termux-packages.list                                                               deb [trusted=yes arch=all] https://ivam3.github.io/termux-packages stable extras

# root-repo (sources.list.d/root.list)

deb https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-root root stable

# x11-repo (sources.list.d/x11.list)

deb https://mirrors.cbrx.io/apt/termux/termux-x11 x11 main

# sources.list.d/termux-desktop-xfce.list

deb [trusted=yes arch=all] https://Yisus7u7.github.io/termux-desktop-xfce/packages desktop-xfce extras

# tur-repo (sources.list.d/tur.list)                                                                      deb https://tur.kcubeterm.com tur-packages tur tur-on-device tur-continuous
```

Updatable packages:

```
beef/stable 0.5.4.0-soa all [upgradable from: 0.5.4.0-dev]

i-haklab/stable 3.7.0 all [upgradable from: 3.6.7]                                                        nodejs/stable 20.2.0 aarch64 [upgradable from: 19.6.1]
```

- termux-tools version: 1.38.3                                                                                                    - Android version: 13
- Kernel build information: Linux localhost 4.14.186-g584a03637-dirty #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 16 15:17:01 CST 2023 aarch64 Android
- Device manufacturer: vivo
- Device model: V2117

LD Variables:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib

LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libtermux-exec.so
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.